# Print thread stack of all threads of a process

Tags: .net, threadpool, callstack

I have a .NET application with a button. When I click the button I want the application to print thread stack of all threads to debug console.

Is it possible to do it?

Datte.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StackTrace` class (`System.Diagnostics`) to get a stack trace of a `Thread`.   You'd need to enumerate the threads, and (unfortunately) suspend them first, though.

Here's the constructor of interest:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2k35tat.aspx

You may well need to create your own `ThreadPool` implementation, or extend someone else's.  As far as I can see/tell there's no way to enumerate them.

Comment: There is a big warning about not using that constructor as it might well cause deadlocks..

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to someone finding this question http://stackdump.codeplex.com/